# use raw html in php

Tags: php, html, echo

I want to keep my html code in a variable and then echo it once in PHP. here is the code I use for this:
[my code](http://www.8pic.ir/images/91106514512401183343.jpg)

Note: I use the code's image here as I got formatting error upon posting this question.
But I constantly get this error:
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in E:\wamp\www\test.php on line 18**

PHP version: 5.4.3
I use WAMP 2.2

Any idea on how I can fix this to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you even want to put HTML into a variable? Then echo it? Just output it directly!

Comment: There can be no spaces before `EOD;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end tag, EOD;, must be the first thing on a new line. Otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: It worked when I put ending EOD as the first thing in a newline as you said.Thanks. this is my output now: [link](http://www.8pic.ir/images/14641109718639476766.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```
EOD;
```

Should be at the beginning of the line, as stated on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). Although this syntax isn't actually required in your situation - just use:

```
<?php
//some php code
?>
<div>
    <!-- my html -->
</div>
<?php
//more php code
?>
```

You can open and close PHP tags as much as you want

Answer (score 0):

Your the heredoc syntax for strings the terminating string has to occur at the beginning of a line.

**Excerpt From The Docs**

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except possibly a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. The closing delimiter (possibly followed by a semicolon) must also be followed by a newline.

See the Warning highlighted [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)